# Can't locate some text using xpath from certain elements

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to locate the name within "value" attribute from the below elements using xpath:

```
<div class="div_input_place">
    <input name="txt_name" type="text" value="ANWESH SHETTY" maxlength="20" id="txt_name" disabled="disabled" tabindex="2" class="aspNetDisabled textboxDefault_de_active_student">
</div>
```

I've tried with the below expression but found no result:

```
//input[@value]/text()
```

Comment: `//input/@value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//input[@value]/text()` would locate an `input` element which has `value` attribute, then it would get you the "text" of the element - which is empty.

What you need instead is to locate the `input` element, for instance, by `id` and then get the value of the `value` attribute:

```
//input[@id = "txt_name"]/@value
```

Comment: Sir alecxe, I suppose you wanna take a look into the script where I've used your suggested xpath. The link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636853/trouble-parsing-the-first-name-from-a-webpage"