# Trouble parsing the "First name" from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How can I get the "First Name" from the target page in my script. I've tried like below but it throws the following error:

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class="div_input_place"]/input[@id="txt_name"]/@value" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element."
```

However, the element within which the "First Name" I'm after:

```
<div class="div_input_place">
                                                <input name="txt_name" type="text" value="CLINTO KUNJACHAN" maxlength="20" id="txt_name" disabled="disabled" tabindex="2" class="aspNetDisabled textboxDefault_de_active_student">
                                            </div>
```

The script I've tried with so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.icaionlineregistration.org/StudentRegistrationForCaNo.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id('txtRegistNo').send_keys('SRO0394294')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnProceed').click()
time.sleep(5)
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="div_input_place"]/input[@id="txt_name"]/@value')
print(name.text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Selenium` doesn't support this syntax. Your `XPath` expression should return `WebElement` only, but not attribute value or text. Try to use below code instead:

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="div_input_place"]/input[@id="txt_name"]').get_attribute('value')
print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your effective solution.

Answer (score 3):

*You cannot target the attributes with XPaths in Selenium* - the expressions have to always match the actual elements:

```
name_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="div_input_place"]/input[@id="txt_name"]')
name_attribute = name_element.get_attribute("value")
print(name_attribute)
```

Note that I'd also switch to a more concise and readable CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.div_input_place input#txt_name')
```

Or, even go with "find by id" if your id is unique:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("txt_name")
```

Comment: `get_attribute()` method is not applicable to `webdriver` instance. Did you mean `name_attribute = name_element.get_attribute("value")`?

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your robust solution. I've upvoted it.